# Cant Seem To Print Answer From User Interface

Tags: javascript

```js
const poll = {
  registerNewAnswer: function() {
    prompt(`
Which is your favourite Movie?
0: Toy Story
1: Star Wars
2: Fast & Furious
3: Final Destination
(Write option number)`);
  }
}

let a = Number(poll.registerNewAnswer());

console.log(a);
```

Comment: You don't return anything from your function. And a simple return statement would just return whatever the user enters, not necessarily from one of your choices. Seems like there's some more logic missing

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to a [MCVE] when asking questions here. The shortest code that would actually reproduce this problem is `function foo() { 3 }; console.log(foo())`. In pairing your code down to the smallest example that still reproduces your problem, you will very often isolate the problem and understand how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function isn't **returning** the value of prompt.

```js
const poll = {
  registerNewAnswer: function() {
    return prompt(`
Which is your favourite Movie?
0: Toy Story
1: Star Wars
2: Fast & Furious
3: Final Destination
(Write option number)`);
  }
}

let a = Number(poll.registerNewAnswer());

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the chosen option from the function.

```js
const poll = {
  registerNewAnswer: function() {
    const option = prompt(`
      Which is your favourite Movie?
      0: Toy Story
      1: Star Wars
      2: Fast & Furious
      3: Final Destination
      (Write option number)`);
    return Number(option);
  }
}

let a = poll.registerNewAnswer();

console.log(a);
```